Why do I get different results when count values in an empty column?
Assuming I have a table containing 1,000 rows, why do the results differ when I employ two distinct methods to count a data item that doesn't exist within the table?
method_1: select count(*)=0 from domains where id=8888;
display_1:
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

method_2: select count(*)=0 from domains limit 1 offset 8888;
display_2:
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)


count(*) is an aggregate that returns only a single row. If you offset on that query, you get nothing.

You also seem to be under the impression that the rows are stored in order by id and that is not the case as SQL is unordered by default.

Two very different queries where the second one will never return a result

The limit and offset clauses are applied after the count aggregate, whereas the where clause is applied before counting.
You can change this by using a subquery, try

select c = 0 from (select count(*) as c from domains) as sub where c = 8888;
select count(*) = 0 from (select * from domains limit 1 offset 8888) as sub;

for comparison
